# PHP Table Not Created From Syntax

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla3.1

I am attempting to query my SQL Server and generate a table of the results.  I have the below syntax, but the table is not being generated.  Am I setting this up incorrectly?  What should I change so that the table properly generates?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
        $option = array();
        $option['driver'] = 'mssql';
        $option['host'] = '555.24.24.18';
        $option['user'] = 'user';
        $option['password'] = 'password';
        $option['database'] = 'database1';
        $option['prefix'] = '';
        $db = JDatabase::getInstance($option);
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
?>
<html>
<html>
    <div>
        <table frame="hsides" style="color:#ffffff;" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Header 1 </th>
                    <th>Header 2 </th>
                    <th>Header 3 </th>
                    <th>Header 4 </th>
                    <th>Header 5 </th>
                    <th>Header 6 </th>
                    <th>Header 7 </th>
                    <th>Header 8 </th>
                    <th>Header 9 </th>
                    <th>Header 10 </th>
                    <th>Header 11 </th>
                    <th>Header 12 </th>
                    <th>Header 13 </th>
                    <th>Header 14 </th>
                    <th>Header 15 </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <table border="1">
            <?php
                $query1 = //Select statement goes here
                $db->setQuery($query1);
                $query1 = $db->loadObjectList();
                if ($query1) 
                {
                    if ($query1->num_rows > 0) 
                    {
                        echo "<table>";
                        foreach ($query1 as $res) 
                        {
                            print "<tr>";
                            print "<td>" . $res->field1 . "</td>";
                            print "<td>" . $res->field2 . "</td>";
                            print "<td>" . $res->field3 . "</td>";
                            print "<td>" . $res->field4 . "</td>";
                            print "<td>" . $res->field5 . "</td>";
                            print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field6) . "</td>";
                            print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field7) . "</td>";
                            print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field8) . "</td>";
                            print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field9) . "</td>";
                            print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field10) . "</td>";
                            print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field11) . "</td>";
                            print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field12) . "</td>";
                            print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field13) . "</td>";
                            print "<td>" . round($res->field14) . "%" . "</td>";
                            print "<td>" . round($res->field15) . "%" . "</td>";
                            print "</tr>";
                        }
                        echo "</table>";
                    } 
                    else          
                    {
                        echo "Empty Table.";
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

ERROR - when removing the `<table>` statements[image]

EDIT EDIT EDIT....
Just for clarity's sake this is the current code that I am working with, but NetBeans still presents the error in my above image. -- removed all `<div>` tags as well as only have a begin and end `<html>` tag.  Also, removed all but 1 `<table>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
    $option = array();
    $option['driver'] = 'mssql';
    $option['host'] = '555.24.24.18';
    $option['user'] = 'user';
    $option['password'] = 'password';
    $option['database'] = 'database1';
    $option['prefix'] = '';
    $db = JDatabase::getInstance($option);
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
?>
<table frame="hsides" style="color:#ffffff;" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1 </th>
            <th>Header 2 </th>
            <th>Header 3 </th>
            <th>Header 4 </th>
            <th>Header 5 </th>
            <th>Header 6 </th>
            <th>Header 7 </th>
            <th>Header 8 </th>
            <th>Header 9 </th>
            <th>Header 10 </th>
            <th>Header 11 </th>
            <th>Header 12 </th>
            <th>Header 13 </th>
            <th>Header 14 </th>
            <th>Header 15 </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
        $query1 = //Select statement goes here
        $db->setQuery($query1);
        $query1 = $db->loadObjectList();
        if ($query1) 
        {
            if ($query1->num_rows > 0) 
            {
                foreach ($query1 as $res) 
                {
                    print "<tr>";
                    print "<td>" . $res->field1 . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . $res->field2 . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . $res->field3 . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . $res->field4 . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . $res->field5 . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field6) . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field7) . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field8) . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field9) . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field10) . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field11) . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field12) . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->field13) . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . round($res->field14) . "%" . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . round($res->field15) . "%" . "</td>";
                    print "</tr>";
                }
            } 
            else          
            {
                echo "Empty Table.";
            }
        }
    ?>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: What does happen? Did you write a `select` statement? Why'd you make 2 `table`s?

Comment: Yes I have a select statement.  I removed it from my post for brevity.  I did not think I was making two tables, I just thought I was writing the headers then writing the data?

Comment: `<table>` creates a new table every time. You could have a `tbody`. That's more a display issue then PHP though. What happens with the PHP? You get an error, wrong results, no results, other?

Comment: I get a header row then no results.  I know the syntax for my query is sound as if I run it in SSMS it returns the expected result set.  And thanks for the tip about the `<table>` syntax.  I thought it would just append to the previous table...guess I shoudl read up on that!

Comment: `vardump($query1)` gives back what? (after execution)

Comment: @IcyPopTarts why do you use `echo` for `<table></table>` but `print` for the `<td>`s?

Comment: @developerwjk - no valid reason, just how I wrote the syntax (lack of knowledge)  In my mind from reading about the two `echo` writes to the screen while `print` writes values (numbers etc)

Comment: View source and see how many `<table` you have. It should show  3, which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: if it shows 3, then the 2nd one is causing the 3rd to not display.  If it shows 2, then the 3rd is not displaying due to the if-condition not being met.

Comment: @developerwjk - you are correct I have 3 open and close tags for `<table>`

Comment: @developerwjk - In Netbeans if I paste it in w/ only two tables my last `</html>` at the very end of my code is underlined and I get an error of 'Syntax Error: Unexpected End Of File'

Comment: take the 2nd one out, see what happens. Maybe in your particular browser because you have a table inside another table but not in a `<tr><td>` it doesn't display. I.e. you have `<table><table><tr><td>` rather than `<table><tr><td><table><tr><td>`

Comment: @developerwjk - when I remove those statements I get the error I included in my edited OP

Comment: You've got two `<html>` tags at the beginning. And you've got a lot of unecessary HTML. The `<div>` tags are pointless.  You really need the headers to be in the same table as the data.  You've got not `<body>`.

Comment: I removed all the `div` tags and only left a beginning and an end `<html>` tags, but NetBeans is still presenting the error in the image if I hover over the red excelmation point on the last line of my syntax.  Which just happens to be the `</html>`

Comment: `$query1 = //Select statement goes here` - I for one would like to know what that is exactly. It's unfinished and stands to be the key to all this. If there's a missing quote or semi-colon in there, that would be the reason for the error.

Comment: and seeing `getQuery()` with the other code with that, tells me you're using some form of library which also stands to be part of the problem. You also have 2x `<html>
<html>`.

Comment: your html markup is also missing `<head></head>` and `<body></body>` tags. Whether or not Netbeans is looking for those or not, is unknown; I'm not familiar with that application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above code you have jumped straight to $db = JDatabase::getInstance($option); without including any classes that define JDatabase. HTML page cannot connect to Joomla API directly. You need to call the base classes before executing any Joomla code. You need to change your code like this

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla' );//YOur Joomla installation Path
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();
```

Rest of your code

You can call the database using

```
$database = JFactory::getDBO();
```